# Netflix and Linux and VM

Tags: streaming, standard, drm, codec

I heard that Netflix needs PlayReady 3.0, Widevine, HEVC 10 bits de/encoder, HDCP 2.2... to play 4K/UHD contents

So I want to know if Linux support these technologies, and if Netflix support those Linux frameworks

I want to know too, if Linux can't, if a VM with W10 can support as is those technologies so Netflix can play 4K medias, or if it can with some pass-through

I know this question doesn't belong completely here but idk where it can belongs otherwise, considering that Netflix support place is the last place to ask that, considering that they don't want to hear about any non official method (and this is normal for a dev. to work hard and clean on supported method but not on unofficial ones). If you know better place doesn't hesitate to tell me

Comment: your questions can  be answered by doing web search ... please post questions here when you do not understand something that you found

Comment: I searched, and this domain is in constant evolution, so that's why I ask if someone knows better

Comment: this is a Q&A site ... not a forum ... not a brainstorming site ... please ask a specific, answerable question about a problem that you are trying to solve ... you come here after you have done research

Comment: 1 - Can Linux plays Netflix 4K contents? Yes/No ; 2 - Can Windows VM plays Netflix 4K contents? Yes/No. My researches haven't given any replies to those

Comment: I think the question is well pissed, documents sufficient research, and is clear on what the request is: what's a good way to watch Netflix without sacrificing quality.